# Is there a free/low-cost bus monitor in VHDL/Verilog for ARM AXI/AXI4 and/or AXI4-Stream protocols?

Tags: arm, hdl

I am looking for something to log the read and writes on an AXI 4 bus to a file. And similar for AXI4-Stream. For what it is worth, this is for Xilinx. I could roll my own, but I hoped someone else had already solved this problem.

Comment: I am very confused by your title.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Xilinx AXI Bus functional model help?

http://www.xilinx.com/ipcenter/axi4.htm has a link to an [AXI BFM Product Brief](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/pb001_axi_bfm.pdf)

Comment: No, that appears to be for driving the bus. I'm looking to monitor it.

Comment: Actually it has a slave too, it's not just for driving the bus. But I still think it isn't what I'm looking for.